# how catch error when doing insertion in batch without frequent commit

Tags: python, database

Suppose I am doing database insertion in the following manner in python, where I ONLY do commit ONCE at the end.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
for data in datas:
    try:
        cursor.execute(insert data sql)
    except:
        ?
connection.commit()
```

How to handle error here, so that those valid inserts pass through and get added, while erroring ones get excluded? For instance, if data is [insert A, insert B, insert C], and B is erroring, I want A and C in database at the end.

I know I can achieve this by doing commit for every insert and rollback when erroring, but how to achieve this with only one commit at the end? Thanks.

Comment: Error checking doesn't wait for commit, it happens immediately. So your code should work.

Comment: I do not think so. If I hit except for one insert, the next insert will give me this error: " current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block". and then the program just gets terminated

Comment: What DBMS are you using? I tested with SQLite3. I tried inserting 1, 2, 1 into a unique column. The third insert raised an exception. Then I committed and the first 2 rows were saved.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I used Postgres